# Why is composer deleting and reinstalling core?

Tags: composer

I am running Drupal 9.2.4 on Lando on Mac Big Sur.  When I use composer to install a module it first deletes core.

```
Removing package drupal/core so that it can be re-installed and re-patched.
 - Removing drupal/core (9.2.4)
```

Then it reinstalls it.

```
 - Installing drupal/core (9.2.4): Extracting archive
```

If the module fails to install, no core!

I think these are the relevant lines from composer.json.

```
"drupal/core": "^9.2.4",
"drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "@stable",
"drupal/core-project-message": "9.2.4",
"drupal/core-recommended": "@stable",
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Have you tried updating cweagans/composer-patches? See this issue. https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches/issues/363

Comment: Composer tells you why it is happening: "Removing package drupal/core so that it can be **re-installed and re-patched.**"

Comment: This is most likely the bug I mentioned and that is why I posted it as an answer, not a comment. I Don't appreciate that being changed.

Comment: @tonytheferg Answers are for answering the question, not asking questions to the OP or merely providing a link. Answers asking for information or merely providing a link are removed.

Comment: Core being deleted and not being re installed is the bug I mentioned. It's not designed behavior for composer patches. There's not much else to say about it.

Answer (score 3):

When there is a patch set in your composer.json file or a composer.json file in one of your packages, composer will remove the package with a patch (in this case core) and reinstall it to apply all the patches. Look for a section that looks something like:

```
"patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "3035113 - EntityAccessChecker": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-10-21/LatestRevisionCheck-13092187-24.patch",
                "2856823 - header links": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-11-24/2856823-48__core-9.1.x.patch",
                "2784233 - Allow multiple vocabularies in the taxonomy filter": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-05-28/2784233-193.patch"      
            }
}
```

If not your composer.json file, check for a composer file of your distribution or profile. That’s the most likely place to find it.

Comment: I do, in fact, have a patches section in my composer file.  Thanks for pointing this out.  This composer file was generated my the Acquia Migrate Accelerator module.   I am wondering if I can safely remove this section?

Comment: Well, that depends. If you are still doing the migrations and need the Acquia Migrate Accelerator module, I would leave it alone. It is likely depending on those patches. Acquia does a good job of checking for updates to core and will remove patches from their module when they're not needed. So be sure to keep up-to-date. Also, be sure your `cweagans/composer-patches` is updated as mentioned by @tonytheferg